# Looking for a distro that has linux kernel 4.0?

Tags: linux, kernel, distribution-choice

The computer I'm looking to upgrade to linux has a wifi card that isn't supported in linux but I read somewhere that it is supported in the 4.0 kernel. Because of this I can't install an old kernel version and then upgrade since it needs an internet connection.

Can anyone point me to a distribution that already has upgraded to the 4.0 kernel?

Comment: Arch Linux has.

Comment: Why don't you just upgrade the kernel in your current distribution? There's no reason to switch distros just to upgrade a kernel!

Comment: in addition to what terdon said, you can always download kernel packages or source code etc to a USB stick on another machine and transfer them to your laptop.  this can be a fair amount of work but so can backing up your data and installing a new distro.

Comment: I disagree with the reasons for closing this.  The question may have more than 1 answer, however it is a valid question that is not too broad to have a single answer in list form.  Regarding the suggestion to 'just upgrade the kernel', this could be catastrophic, and in many cases far worse than 'backing up' due to cascade issues where X version of ABC program is dependent on something that is dependent on something which .... eventually is dependent on Y version at Z build of the kernel, causing most (if not all) programs installed to fail.

Answer (score 1):

[Fedora 22 alpha](http://fedoramagazine.org/linux-kernel-4-0-available-in-fedora-22-alpha/) has got it, Debian and Ubuntu also.
check the [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

[ArchLinux](https://www.archlinux.org/) has always the latest version of the Kernel. Currently: 4.1.6 (2015/09/06).

as F.sb said cheking on DistroWatch is a good idea.